# Qt; Не запускается программа из под IDE

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

Создал новый проект Qt под MSVS-2013, при запуске отладчика выскакивает ошибка об отсутствии Qt5Cored.dll. При всем при этом предыдущие проекты написанные ранее, запускаются без проблем. Люто-бешено реквестирую помощь.

P.S.: Перед запуском конвертировал проект в QMake и обратно в Add-in как и положено.

P.P.S: 28.05 Проблема так и не решена. Неужели никто не сталкивался с такой темой?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что нужно переключиться на 'Release'

Comment: Есть подозрение, что в режиме релиза отлаживать приложение не получится.

Comment: И да, в состоянии релиза он также не видит библиотеку, но уже Qt5Core.dll.

Comment: Где написано что так положено делать?

Comment: Что видно в DependencyWalker`е?

Comment: https://imgdepo.com/show/9287996

Comment: @DarkDeadDragon так а библиотечные файлы на компьютере вообще есть?

Answer (score 5):

Деревянное решение - добавить путь к DLL Qt в PATH.

Если вы используете [Qt Visual Studio Add-in](http://doc.qt.io/vs-addin/), то эту работу должен выполнять он. Причем он делает это неявно, буквально обрабатывает событие о старте отладки и стартуемому процессу добавляет путь к DLL в его копию PATH (кажется при обычном неотладочном старте он делает то же самое). Соответственно путь этот вы должны указать в настройках проекта Qt. Сделано это для того, чтобы можно было компилировать проекты под разные версии Qt. Так вот, помнится, я сталкивался с тем, что аддин в этом месте глючил и прописывал путь через раз.

Нашел [раз](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-392) и [два](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-125). Попробуйте, как по первой ссылке человек пишет, пересобрать аддин.

Вообще, очень сложно судить почему ваша пограмма на вашей машине не находит DLL. Вы писали, что раньше работало, посмотрите что вы делали с системой в этот промежуток времени. И еще, в соотвествии с [МСДН](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications) проверте все ли у вас настроено правильно.

Comment: Во первых не те ошибки (на эти статьи я гуглив тоже напарывался), во вторых не помогло.

Comment: Ну и в третьих - все пути присутствуют. Все проекты, которые  я писал ранее, спокойно компилируются и запускаются без каких либо ошибок от  системы.

Comment: @DarkDeadDragon Какие и где пути присутствуют?

Comment: https://imgdepo.com/show/9273228
https://imgdepo.com/show/9273232

Comment: Нет решения? Кстати, в предложенных вами ссылках указаны совершенно другие версии, как IDE так и Qt.

Comment: @DarkDeadDragon Так что, если в PATH прописать тоже не работает?

Comment: Оно и сейчас работает с предыдущими проектами, а с новыми нет!

Comment: Cerbo не никак. Просто тупик. Как-будто компилятор не видит папку. Но почему-то только на новых проектах.

Comment: @DarkDeadDragon Как раз компилятор все видит, иначе бы он вам не собрал проект. DLL подмапывает к процессу загрузчик, он ищет их в порядке расписанном по ссылке указанной мной в ответе. еще раз, вы точно добавляли путь к Qt в переменную среды PATH и старт не выполнялся?

Comment: и еще раз да. Сто раз, на ста новых проектах - ноль эффекта.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте настройки проекта. Скорей всего ошибка в линковщике (неправильно прописан или не прописан путь)

Comment: Настройки пути абсолютно совпадают с настройками предыдущих проектов. Они даже в одной директории расположены. Плюс, по умолчанию встает версия QT та, что (простите за каламбур) установлена по умолчанию. А она у меня установлена одна.

Answer (score 1):

Есть кривое, абсолютно корявое решение, но оно дает хоть что-то - таскать нужные dll в папке с проектом. Я понимаю что так не правильно, но другого решения не нашел.

Comment: Поясню вам как новичку, что здесь на РУСО, запрещены обсуждения или ссылки на любые политические, религиозные, национальные или иные темы не связанные с айти и программированием в частности, для других тем есть другие площадки. Не приветвуются также использование мемов, так как они живут не долго и через продолжительное время становятся не понятными посетителям.

Comment: Скучно так жить...

Comment: @DarkDeadDragon для лулзов у нас есть чатик(и), присоединяйтесь. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: А вообще мы тут ненавидим юмор )) http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2697/181472

Comment: @Cerbo а что там про политические обсуждения? Я не нашёл даже следа их на этой странице.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Историю изменений ответа смотрите